# Adding Tags to a Pull Request

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-tag

I have a repo [iontech/Anagen](http://github.com/iontech/Anagen) forked from [agiliq/Anagen](http://github.com/agiliq/Anagen)

I made a few commits to my fork and added a tag. Then I opened a Pull Request. This Pull Request includes only my commits.

How do I include the tag I've created into the Pull Request?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> How do I include the tag I've created into the Pull Request?

You can't. A pull request does not include tags. A pull request is only a pointer to a thread of commits (a branch) in your repository that you're proposing another repository to merge.

If you want to notify the upstream repository that a tag should be created, maybe should you add a comment to the pull request explaining this.

Comment: Just curious what could possibly be the reason for such a restriction? (If by chance you happen to be one of the github support staff?)

Comment: A Pull Request only contains commits.

Comment: Well the tag is for that Pull Request right? Why does it matter if a Pull Request contains only commits? (I'm just trying to wrap my head around that decision)

Comment: One can add a tag to a commit in his/her own repository. A pull request only reference the tip of a branch (ie. the last commit). As such the tag won't be embedded in the Pull Request.

Comment: I tried to create a tag after merging the pull request but it went under the old tag?

Comment: This is unfortunate.  I see no way to request from the repository maintainer that they create a new tag (or release).  If the repository does not use "Issues" tracker, the only option is to directly contact the maintainer _if_ they have provided a way to contact them.

It is a weakness in git that tags cannot be tracked as commits are.

Comment: The "Pull Request" only containing commits is most likely a GitHub policy, but it follows from the git design/intended use of tags - tags are mainly meant to annotate shared history, and by definition a PR isn't history yet.  So tags normally don't move... would be better to create a branch and share that (it's part of a PR).

Answer (score 35):

This is an old post but i fell on this while searching for something similar, i'll give you a more complete explanation.

Tags and branches in git are called references or "refs". You can move a ref anytime you want to a new commit and thus create loose commits if you move backwards in time. Even worst, those commits could be lost over time if pruned out because they are waiting in the void.

When you submit a PR, you actually ask someone to merge a list of commits in your repository referenced by your branch name (your ref) with a list of commits in a remote repository identified also by a ref (the base branch). If you have commits that are not present in your repository (you aren't up to date) and some of your commits actually touch places of code that you don't have on your side, then a merge needs to be done to resolve conflicts. If you aren't up to date but your code doesn't touch what has been modified since then, there won't be a conflict.

Finally, when stuff is getting merged into another repository, often, it will be squashed to save commit history creating a completely new commit hash and a new tree structure of commits.

Taken what i explained so far, that tags are just references just like branches. If you open a PR between two repositories' references that are branch references, then there is no way to create a tag because you are not creating any new refs in the end, you are just asking someone to take your commits into his code and move the base branches reference forward to the new commit after everything is merged in!

The best and only method really becomes to ask the maintainer to issue a release for his code by tagging if that's the way they do it but that is to their discretion!

Comment: Technically, it's still possible, but difficult to implement yeh? Like Github could have come up with some tag merging workflow or tag conflict resolution, etc. but this is just not currently built, yeh?

Comment: Not so much "difficult to implement" but more like "abusing the notion of tags".  I found this nice writeup which points to a few other resources (back here on SO), but start here: https://sarakhandaker.medium.com/tags-in-git-git-tags-vs-git-branching-c8aa03723c14