# How to get git tags from a fork into the main repo?

Tags: git

Im working on a fork of a repo. Ive push a tag to my fork. How can I get this tag into the main repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Tags to a Pull Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278660/adding-tags-to-a-pull-request)

Comment: @ChrisMaes Im asking what is the usual way of doing this, not specifically how to do it via a pull request.

Comment: I understand. You just remove the sentence talking about putting it in a pull request. The link remains valid as a reference...