# Azure DevOps Pipeline structure for PRs in mono-repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a mono-repo containing multiple sub-projects (Node/TypeScript if it matters). I'm trying to set up what I feel is a relatively simple pull request setup in Azure DevOps that is meant to deploy a PR environment for testing. It consists of 2 pipelines that I want to trigger one after the other in the PR. If either fail the PR should fail as well. The code is hosted in Azure DevOps Git.

Here are the steps I'm trying to achieve:

1. PR is created with tag `solution-a` for merging from `features/feature-x` to `dev` branch
2. Branch policy triggers the `solution-a-pipeline` based on the tag `solution-a`. A different pipeline should be triggered if the tag is different.
3. `solution-a-pipeline` triggers `infrastructure-pipeline` and `solution-a-build-pipeline` in context of `features/feature-x` branch* in order.
4. If `solution-a-pipeline` completes successfully (indirectly this means `infrastructure-pipeline` and `solution-a-build-pipeline` also completed successfully in order) the bulid is considered successful. Otherwise it fails and the PR cannot be completed.

*By "in context" I mean that the actual yaml file used for each pipeline is the one from the feature branch. This is because I want it to test any changes to the pipelines as well as any steps within the pipeline.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've been trying for days now using different combinations of pipeline files, templates, resources and triggers and I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Do you use GitHub or Azure DevOps Repos?

Comment: Azure DevOps Repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to work around the problem. It involves several steps and some hard-coding, but I'm now able to tag a Pull Request with certain defined tags and have a Build Validation triggered `pipeline` run only the relevant parts as a result.

My setup consists of one big `pr-pipeline.yml` file that is triggered by the Build Validation of PRs to my `dev` branch. The trigger is manual, but required which allows the person issuing the PR to tag it accordingly before it begins.

Once the pipeline runs the very first step uses the Azure DevOps REST API to determine which tags are present on the associated PR by calling this endpoint:

```
https://dev.azure.com/$(organizationName)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/labels?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Every parameter required except the organization name is provided by the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the pipeline.

To call the endpoint I'm using the Personal Access Token (PAT) provided to the agent by Azure DevOps in the predefined variable `System.AccessToken` and a small PowerShell script:

```
$accessToken = "$(System.AccessToken)"
$basicAuth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$accessToken"))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $basicAuth"}
$url = $(url)
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prlabels]$data"
```

Once I have my tags I extract each of them as a separate variable using a small PowerShell snippet. The `prlabels` variable is populated by :

```
$tagsJson = '$(prlabels)' | ConvertFrom-Json
$tags = $tagsJson.value | ForEach-Object { $_.name }
Write-Host "Tags: $($tags -join ";")"
$tags | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prlabel_$_;isOutput=true]true" }
```

If my pr is tagged with `solution-a` and `solution-c` this will result in the following output variables being defined:

```
prlabel_solution-a = true
prlabel_solution-c = true
```

Finally, I can use those output variables as conditions for triggering the relevant jobs that perform the actual build and deployments for the respective solutions. The job that fetches the tags is named `PreReq` and the task that outputs individual variables is named `prlabels`:

```yaml
- job: DeploySolutionA
  dependsOn: PreReq
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.PreReq.outputs['prlabels.prlabel_solution-a'], 'true'))
  # ...
```

All of this together enables me to deploy one or more specific solutions in a PR based on what the user defines. It still requires the user to know of these labels, but at least they don't have to manually start each pipeline on each run outside of the PR.

Comment: Note that I've actually split the pipeline into several smaller templates and I'm using job conditions to conditionally trigger each template based on the tags. So you don't need a massive pipeline, only one that orchestrates the entire thing and then passes on control to individual templates as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Pipeline structure for PRs in mono-repo

I could understand your requests, but AFAI for Azure devops, I do not believe there is such a way to achieve your needs at this moment.

There are three challenges here:

1. We could not add a tag to a Pull Request, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278660/adding-tags-to-a-pull-request) for details.
2. We could not trigger different build pipeline based on the tags. There is no such condition for the option build validation.
3. We could not set the order of the build validation. We could set multiple build pipeline in the build validation, but we could not set the order of them. If we add a build validation and use build completion to set the build order, but build validation will only verify the results of the build pipeline we added, not the results of other associated pipelines

In summary, I do not believe there is such a way to achieve your needs at this moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I actually managed to get most of it working by using the REST api to fetch labels/tags for the active PR during the build and then routing accordingly. It worked surprisingly well. Unfortunately now I'm stuck attempting to pass a variable from a deployment job to a subsequent job. I've followed the instructions here to the letter yet I cannot get the value out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for your reply. That means you are not using option build validation directly, instead you are using REST API, if yes, I may misunderstood your question. Sorry. Since you have already managed to get most of it working by using the REST api, you may need to update your question to be more clear, like you said in the comment, some more code sample will be better. Thanks.

Comment: I've set up a pipeline that I will in turn trigger using Build Validation. It will fetch the tags from the associated PR and set global variables accordingly. Based on them I will then run the respective builds.
This allows me to tag the PR with Solution-A and Solution-C and, once the pipeline is triggered it reads these tags and starts each build.

So yes, I'm planning on using Build Validation to trigger builds, I'm just reading the tags using the REST api from a PowerShell task inside the pipeline and setting variables based on it.

Comment: Just to add. If this works I intend to publish an answer here describing my solution. I just need to get cross-job variables working. Not even the documented example seems to work (I've copied it into a clean pipeline to test)

Comment: if you could possibly have a look at this question I'd greatly appreciate it. I suspect that I'm just missing something basic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476512/azure-devops-pipeline-define-variable-in-deployment-and-reuse-in-subsequent-job

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for your sharing, I will check that thread after I get out of the current thread.